# After take a picture and save it, sometimes the program crashes, doesn't return to the activity

Tags: java, android, image

I'm calling the function `dispatchTakePictureIntent` to take a picture. But after I take the picture and save it, the application doesn't returns correctly to the actual activity, the application crashes.

When my button is pressed I call

```
dispatchTakePictureIntent(1);
```

then:

```
public void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {

        try {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File f = createImageFile();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    /*  Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);*/
    }

    public File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        final String nomeForm = "teste";    
        String imageFileName = nomeForm +".jpeg";


       File path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
       File image = new File(path,imageFileName );

       // String getAbsolutePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +  image, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return image;
    }
```

my logcat error report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.example.sform/com.example.sform.mainRisco}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sform/com.example.sform.risco1}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/0x1. Make sure other views do not use the same id.
```

Here all my layouts:

Tab Host Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layout_riscos">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

The Tab1:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/risco1"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/geral_risco1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="739dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:screenOrientation="nosensor" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pelicula_risco1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Take a Picture ;)"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_risco1"
        android:layout_width="9000dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pelicula"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </ImageView>


    <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/riscoQ1_risco1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The Tab2:

```
  <TextView android:text="risco 2"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/text_risco2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Tab3:

```
  <TextView android:text="risco 3"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_risco3"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Tab4:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/geral_risco4">

  <TextView android:text="risco 4"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_risco4"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Tab5:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/geral_risco5" >

  <TextView android:text="risco 5"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_risco5"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:screenOrientation="nosensor" 
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
  >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Another screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:screenOrientation="nosensor" 
android:id="@+id/scroll_tela_form"
>

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

     android:id="@+id/info2"
>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dataAnalise"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/getDate"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/horaAnaliseFixo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/horaAnalise"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dataAnalise"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Hora de Inicio da Análise"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nomeForm"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Data da Análise"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nomeForm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/getDate"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="NomeForm"
        android:textSize="34dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/horaAnalise"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/horaAnaliseFixo"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/getDate"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/horaAnaliseFixo"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="41dp"
        android:text="Get Date" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/getDate"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Get Time" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please show your logcat error report

Comment: Can you post exception stack trace here?

Comment: I added the logcat error report

Comment: are you getting image from url ??

Comment: I'm getting from a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another reason for this issue can be two (or more) layout files for the same layout stored under `layout`, `layout-land`, `layout-w600dp` etc. If these layouts have views of different types sharing same id, then you can get this exception two. To reproduce the exception you need to call function `dispatchTakePictureIntent()`, then rotate your device, then take picture and return back. Does it help?

Comment: I've configurated the application to be on the vertical, but if I hold  my Tablet in the horizontal position when I take the picture works, doesn't crash

Comment: That's what I mean. If it works when you keep orientation unchanged and fails when you change orientation while a picture is taken, then the issue is that you have same layout in two or more folders. To solve the issue make sure you don't use same id for views of different types.

Comment: I've changed all my layouts to:
android:orientation="vertical"
android:screenOrientation="nosensor" , 

and in AndroidManifest I'm using in all activities:
android:screenOrientation="portrait"

The error persists, maybe because to take the picture, the screen is flipped to horizontal orientation

Comment: Could you post all your layout files? I mean really all, from all layout-* folders.

Comment: Done, I've posted all the layouts

Comment: According to error trace, you have two activities: mainRisco and risco1. In the question there is only one activity. What is the relation between mainRisco and risco1? Can you post onActivityResult() too?

Answer (score 0):

You have used same `id` for two different views.

Check your layout `XML` & use different `ids` for different views.

Comment: Is it solving the problem?

Comment: I've already checked, and I'm not using the same Id. I'm using tabs, could this be the problem?

Comment: can you post layout xml here?

Answer (score 0):

It says that you are using the same id for different views and that the id is 0x1. That looks suspiciously like

a) somewhere a view id is expected, something else is given or

b) the R.java is generated incorrectly. Please check if theres an id of 1 in there somewhere.

Did you check the value of

```
@android:id/tabs
@android:id/tabcontent
```

?

Comment: Maybe that is the problem, because android:id/tabs and android:id/tabcontent are not in R.java

Comment: the android: prefix means they are system constants from android. Try replacing them with normal @+id/... values